# Id not getting passed to Partial View form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Parent View:
`@Html.Action("SetReview", "Review", new {sellerId = Model.SellerId})`

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult SetReview(string sellerId)
        {
            return PartialView("_Review", new Finder.Models.Review()
            {
                SellerId = sellerId
            });
        }
```

This is the part where the Id is not getting passed

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SetReview(Finder.Models.Review review)
        {
            var review2 = new Review()
            {
                PersonId = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                SellerId = review.SellerId,
                Rating = review.Rating,
                IsAnonymous = review.IsAnonymous,
                CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Content = review.Content,
            };
            DbContext.Reviews.Add(review2);
            DbContext.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { status = "true", msg = "Successfully processed" });
        }
```

No idea what's going wrong here. Shouldn't the get function pass the model to the post one, and the review.Id not get lost?

Comment: Im confused. What's being called? The `post` or the `get`? Where is The `post` being called from? All this line here is doing `return PartialView("_Review", new Finder.Models.Review()` is returning a partial view. It would never call the code in the `post`

Comment: Your  `@Html.Action` is a `GET`. Where are you doing your `POST`?

Answer (score 0):

SellerId actually is in get method when you call get method and u see your view seller id is null bcos your not post it you need seller id in your post method just it !

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code it will hit your post method

```
@using Finder.Models
@model Review
<form asp-controller="Review" asp-action="SetReview" method="post">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  @Html.Action("SetReview", "Review", new {sellerId = Model.SellerId})
               </div>
               <div class="col-12">
               <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn bg-blue"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>Save</button>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```